# MongoDB aggregate from array field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following collection:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("52e7aa3ed3d55b9b01e23f34"),
  "time" : mytime,
  "type_instance" : "",
  "values" : [0.23, 0.08, 0.06],
  "types" : ["type0", "type1", "type2"]
}
```

I want to group by time to get the average of the values per index. The desired result would be something like:

```
{
  "time" : mytime,
  "values" : [avg 0, avg 1, avg 2],
  "types" : ["type0", "type1", "type2"]
}
```

I tried to aggregate

```
collection.aggregate([
                   {   "$match": {'time':  {"$gte": start}

                                 } 
                   }
                   ,{    "$project": {
                           "time":"$time",
                           "values":  "$values"                   
                       }
                   }

                   ,{   
                       "$group": {"_id": "$time", "avg": {avg:"$values[0]"}}
                   }

                   ,{
                       "$sort": {"time": 1}
                   }
                      ], function(err, data) {});
```

Off course this doesn't work, I can't use "$values[0]".
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I tink the model is quite different: {{value, type},{value, type}} Vs {{value1, value2},{type1, type2}}

Comment: I guess what you want isn't possible at the moment https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4589 , accessing an array element like $values.0 only works in the $match step (aggregation) or in normal queries

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem could be with your document structure because your want to link indirectly the values from the `values` field to the ones in `types` field, maybe something like this would be more convenient:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("52e7aa3ed3d55b9b01e23f34"),
   "time" : mytime,
   "type_instance" : "",
   "whatever":[{
        "type": 0,
        "value": 0.23
   },{
        "type": 1,
        "value": 0.08
   },{
        "type": 2,
        "value": 0.06
   }]
}
```

This way you could group by time and type (or index as I think you referred to it) after unwinding the `whatever` field:

```
collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$whatever"},
    {$match: {"time": ...},
    {$group:{
        _id: {"$time", "$whatever.type"},
        avg: {$avg: "$whatever.value"}
    }}
])
```

This way you will get N documents per time group, being N = number of types or subdocuments in the `whatever` field.